# Is a circle a form?

Tags: impermanence, form, name

Nobody has ever seen a circle. Yet we all say "that is a circle" and nod in agreement. But when we say that the top of a bottle is a circle, we see the bottle top, not really the circle. The recognition of a circle is impermanent. We are taught to recognize a circle in school and are given its name as "circle".

Nobody has ever drawn a circle. We can only draw a rough form that is recognized as a "circle" but is actually not a circle. And it's not a circle because circles are made of points with no width, so a drawing of a circle can never be the circle we recognize.

So then we ask, "What is a circle?"
And in response comes the chorus, "A circle is a form".

Except that the Buddha says:

> [SN22.55:3.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.55/en/sujato#sn22.55:3.1): They don’t truly understand form—which is impermanent—as impermanent.

So if a circle is a form, it must be impermanent. But wait. How can this be?  Beyond our deaths and the forgetting of the circle, others will be born who will be taught to recognize a circle as "circulo" or "Kreis" or whatever. And our children and their children will agree that these words define the same form.

Is a circle a form and if so, how can we understand what the Buddha means when he says that form is impermanent?

Comment: I guess "a circle" is or has a definition (e.g. it's "a line at constant distance/radius from the centre point"). And, specific physical drawings (instances) illustrate or approximate that definition. And I'm posting this as a comment because if I posted it as an answer I don't see how it's related to Buddhism.

Comment: Maybe "a circle" is a name, too -- we see lots of things, a teacher says, "look there's a circle" and we look. Stuff in our brain learns language (especially when we're young), and classifies more-or-less circular shapes as being so-called, recognisable circles.

Comment: @ChrisW, this question arose in regard to my answer to transmigration having no beginning with the circle analogy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A circle is a convention.
A circle is like an illusion.
A circle is a useful agreement.
A circle is like a magic trick.
A circle is a conceptual fiction.
A circle is a conditioned phenomena.

There is no circle,
In any place,
At any time,
Known by anyone.

Comment: The recognition of a circle is a conditioned phenomenon. And I have never seen, felt, smelled, touched or tasted a circle at any time in any place.  Thank you.

Comment: @OyaMist A circle is a mind-object isn't it, i.e. "known" and not [just] "seen" or "touched"?

Comment: Yes. It is a thought (the sixth sense)--and even here it is impermanent being conditioned by teaching, genes or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

When the Buddha says that form is impermanent, he's referring to the fact that what we take to be enduring physical structures are actually characterized by their ephemeral nature.  Dogen puts this another way - “The blue mountains are constantly walking. If you doubt mountains walking you do not know your own walking."

Regarding your concept of the circle - the concept only endures so long as there are minds to consider it.  It has no enduring nature of it's own.  It's mutually dependent on person, instantiation, thought, knowledge of geometry, etc.  There is no such thing as a circle outside of these conditions.

Comment: And circles are "reborn" when new minds are conditioned to perceive them.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that's a fair way of looking at it

Answer (score 1):

Circle is a concept. Concepts are without function and therefore permanent.

The "form" in the aggregates is less about shape. It translates from rupa, which generally does mean shape but the way it is used to classify the physical aggregate- aggregate of matter as along with 4 aggregates of mind- come to make 5- namarupa.

Comment: Where does the Buddha say that concepts are permanent?

Comment: Are concepts not conditioned phenomena? Are they not dependent??

Answer (score 0):

AN 3.136 & SN 12.20 says the Laws of Dhamma, including the Law of Impermanence (AN 3.136), are fixed, even when they remain unknown due to the non-appearance of Buddhas (uppādā vā tathāgatānaṁ anuppādā vā tathāgatānaṁ, ṭhitāva sā dhātu dhammaṭṭhitatā dhammaniyāmatā). Therefore, while the visual sight of a circle many be impermanent due to the impermanence of the mind & sense organs perceiving the circle, this is not enough to say the circle is impermanent; just as it is not enough or incorrect to say the Laws of Dhamma are impermanent when the universe only has unenlightened puthujjana.

The circle is impermanent because it is a physical form, i.e., as a planet, a physical structure (such as the circular shape of the ancient city of [Atlantis](https://www.newshub.co.nz/home/world/2018/09/is-this-atlantis-hiding-in-plain-sight-in-the-sahara.html) or a wheel of a cart or car), a drawing or another physical projection. Anything physical ('rupa'), such as a planet, Atlantis, a chart wheel, a car tyre, etc, is liable to impermanence, to wearing away and erosion, to breaking up and destruction ([AN 9.15](https://suttacentral.net/an9.15/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=true&script=latin)).

Comment: > [AN3.136:1.6](https://suttacentral.net/an3.136/en/sujato#an3.136:1.6): Whether Realized Ones arise or not, this law of nature persists, this regularity of natural principles, this invariance of natural principles:  A mathematical circle is a definition, not a law of nature. What we see are things that look like circles. We see "cicular", not circles.

Comment: This comment is lost in Brahminism.

Comment: I was actually agreeing with you that a circle is impermanent, and that the mathematical notion of a perfect circle persisting thru eternity is simply a convenient illusion taught to us. Thanks for the AN3.136 quote. It was quite helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Circle is a form.I think you are talking about stationary, 2 dimensional, drawn on paper,drawn with pencil,a full Circle because there are incomplete circles, half circles, part circle part square circles , part circle part hexagon circles , part circle part trapezoid circles , point circles, circle with borders circles , 3 dimensional circles, 2 dimensional circle , 1 dimensional circle , 4 dimensional circle , expanding circle , contracting circle , impermanent circles, circles drawn on water circles , circles drawn on paper circles , circles drawn on soil circle , circles drawn in the imagination circle, circle drawn with pencil circle,circle drawn with pen circle , circle drawn with finger circle.

I think I gave the full list of possible circles.

You are interested in stationary, 2   dimensional, drawn on paper,drawn with pencil ,a full Circle. You want to know whether such a circle is impermanent or not.I think it is impermanent for various reasons.

1. Circle is a sight. If eyes are impermanent then can circle be permanent? No
2. Circle is drawn with pencil. Pencil color fades away. If pencil color is impermanent then can the circle be permanent? No.
3. Circle is drawn on paper. Paper becomes old and decays. If paper is impermanent then can the circle be permanent? No.
4. Circle is stationary. If wind velocity is impermanent and can shake the paper then can circle remain a circle always ? No.
5. Circle is 2 dimensional. While drawing circle you etched it on the paper creating a little depression on the paper. Can we call the circle only 2 dimensional?No. Your definition of circle changes.
6. Circle is a full circle. While drawing circle if the ends do not meet exactly then does it fail to be circle ? No. Your definition of circle changes.

Your Circle clearly is impermanent because it arises in mind and paper, changes due to decay of pencil color and wind velocity  ,and vanishes because paper ages and decays.

Even if you put the paper drawn full circle in a vaccum chamber it will decay, that’s the prediction of science and Buddha. Have Faith. Metta.

Comment: I am going blind but I can still feel something as "circular" and I can show you that so that you could see that it is like a circle. But neither one of us has every seen or felt an actual mathematical circle. We have both seen and felt objects that we recognize as "circular", but that drawing of a circle isn't an actual "circle". It's a facsimile of a circle drawn with a pencil or pen or whatever.  The question I needed answered was whether a mathematical circle is a Buddhist form.  And what @YesheTenly answered is essentially "yes", since that definition is conditioned.